# authenticate_or_request_with_http_token returning html instead of json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-api

I've created a rails-api application and proceeded to secure it using token authentication.

I've set a `before_filter` that is calling a method which uses `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`. Everything is working fine but, when the authentication is incorrect i'm getting an html response.

How can I define what format the response should be?

```
before_filter :restrict_access

private

def restrict_access
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    check_token token
  end
end

def check_token(token)
  Session.exists?(access_token: token)
end
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code so people can actually help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By including `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods` you include several methods, amongst others `request_http_token_authentication` which is simply a wrapper around `Token.authentication_request`. That `#authentication_request`-method is the culprit and sends the plain text (not HTML as your question suggests) as follows:

```
def authentication_request(controller, realm)
  controller.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
  controller.__send__ :render, :text => "HTTP Token: Access denied.\n", :status => :unauthorized
end
```

The trick is to override `request_http_token_authentication` in your `ApplicationController` to *not* call `Token.authentication_request` but to set the correct status and headers and then render JSON instead. Add this to your `ApplicationController`:

```
protected
def request_http_token_authentication(realm = "Application")
  self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
  render :json => {:error => "HTTP Token: Access denied."}, :status => :unauthorized
end
```

Comment: Currently, you'll have to define this function as `request_http_token_authentication(realm = 'Application', message = nil)`.

Comment: With "currently", do you mean Rails edge, @DiegoCouto?

Comment: That's right @berkes! [Take a look](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L422). Thanks for pointing it out, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From Rails 5, the [authenticate_or_request_with_http_token](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_token) method allows a second parameter with a custom message, so you could just do:

```
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token('realm', json_error) do |token, options|
    check_token token
  end
```